# control inside Wizard <StepNavigationTemplate> tag isn't available in code-behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, wizard, asp.net-controls

I put a Literal control in the  tag in the Wizard control.

In the codebehind, I can't access that control.

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any sort of template control (Wizard, Repeater, etc.) doesn't expose the controls inside the template as member variables.  You will need to use FindControl on the correct Step.

i.e.,

```
var myStep = wizard.Steps[1]; // or however you want to find it
var myLiteral = myStep.FindControl("MyLiteral") as Literal;
```

if you have other templated controls within your wizard Step, you'd need to do a "FindControl" on those as well to continue drilling down to your literal.  I created a "FindControlRecursive" extension method to make this easier.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
Literal literal = MyWizard.FindControl("MyLiteral") as Literal;
if (literal != null)
    // do something with literal
```

(Maybe you tried but how can I know that from your question?)

Comment: I tried, but I used:  this.FindControl as I need this on every wizard step.